# Reading XML file into DataSet and the table has 0 rows, why?

Tags: sql, xml, dataset, vb.net-2010

I am attempting to read an XML File (that is validated by a schema) into the first datatable of a dataset. After doing this and putting a breakpoint in my program, I can see that the datatable has 0 rows. I can not figure out why this is happening...

Here is code sample:

```
Public Sub GitRDone(ByVal sqlDT As DataTable)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim appPath As String = GetAppPath()
        Dim schemaFS As String = appPath & "blah.xsd"
        Dim xmlFS As String = appPath & "blah.xml"

        Try
            ds.Clear()
            ds.EnforceConstraints = False
            ds.ReadXmlSchema(schemaFS)
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFS)
            ds.Tables.Add(sqlDT)
        Catch e As Exception
            MsgBox(e.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Schema sample:

```
<xsd:schema id="HCR_EmployeesSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
targetNamespace="http://www.tempuri.org/MyDataSet.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/MyDataSet.xsd" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">          
<xsd:element name="Employees" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Employee">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="EmployeeID">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                          .....and on......
                      </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

XML Sample:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Employees>
        <Employee>
            <EmployeeID>blah</EmployeeID>
         </Employee>
 </Employees>
```

Comment: I think I may have found my problem... testing now...
For reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/61b43656-86e6-4757-a952-064173b47cd2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. I needed to change my schema attributes from:

```
<xsd:schema id="EmployeesSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
targetNamespace="http://www.tempuri.org/MyDataSet.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/MyDataSet.xsd" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
```

To this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<xsd:schema id="Employees" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
```

The underlying issue here is that my xsd:schema id attribute was wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must have just some trivial error in your logic (maybe the parameter - table - sqlDt - you add to dataset, but is empty - dataset contains other table, that was deserialized and is not empty), serialization works as expected. Sample code (without schema, as you provided incomplete one):

```
using System;

namespace datasetXml
{
    static class Program
    {
        const string xml = 
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeID>blah</EmployeeID>
    </Employee>
</Employees>";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            using (var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(xml))
                ds.ReadXml(sr);
            Console.WriteLine("rows in table: " + ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Above program produces output:
rows in table: 1

Comment: Alright... the C# (or C++) isn't a big problem (I'm using VB.NET) but the difference I see here is that you pass the xml file into a stringReader first and then pass the stringReader to the ReadXML method. My question is now, of course, why? And if you used the above code without a schema, then I guarantee my problem lies within the schema itself.

Comment: OK, I have amended my code to use FileStream and StreamReader, yet, the dataset is still returning 0 rows from the table which it is reading the XML file into.